# Raspberry Pi to be label printer by python

Tags: python, printing, raspberry-pi

I have thermal printer(Star Printer TSP-650) and I want to use Raspberry pi to programming and print a label out by using Python script.Is it possible?  Star Printer TSP-650 is USB output.
I already do same as this video
 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TC9V7cotUgw/ regularly!

Change AMA-0 to USB-0.
My label can print,but it have a little like this ????as???????????? a lot of it.
I want to make it local not like a server too.

Comment: You're not doing a very good job of describing the problem.